# How to automatically create/import some 4000 groups in bulk from a csv file

Tags: import, groups

We are considering data migration to CiviCRM. We have two CSV files, one has the details of thousands of "individuals" and another has a list of over 3000 needed "groups".  Importing process for "individuals" appear to be well documented, but how do we import/create "groups" (including group properties) from a CSV file beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

You could import the groups with the [API CSV importer extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui)

3000 groups is a lot: there may be better ways to represent your data in CiviCRM.  How do you want to use these groups?